# Configure a footer in a word document (page numbers and text)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to set up a Word document out of Excel what actually works pretty well. However, the configuration of the footer is somehow a riddle.

The footer shall contain a date (String from variable `VDate`), a vertical line `|` and a `Page X of Y`. Here's what I've coded so far:

```
...
VDate = "31.03.2022"    'String

Set WordRange = objDoc.Sections(1).Footers(WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

WordRange.Delete

With WordRange
    .Text = VDate & "  |  Page "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.Add WordRange, wdFieldPage        '<-- works until here
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .InsertAfter " of "
    .Fields.Add WordRange, wdFieldNumPages
End With
...
```

After adding the first field `wdFieldPage` the second Collapse does not work and the word `of` is inserted directly after `Page`  and the second field `wdFieldNumPages` comes directly after the first field, leading to this:

```
"31.03.2022 | Page of 11"
```

Can anybody help? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I've worked on it without success so far. Sorry. You might want to be inserting the date as a Document Variable and using a DocVariable field. Then modify the variable with your code and update the fields in the footer. If your documents do not have a footer, consider creating a building block with your footer and inserting that.

Comment: my Preference would be to put a single row table in the footer which is formatted to have a least three cells, two of which will be used for your text.  Turn off the borders of the table except that between the two text items.  Because you are using a table, you can reference the two cells independently.

Comment: @freeflow: Good idea!

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: Thank you for your input. Currently the document date has to be static by request, but I'll consider your comment occasionally.

Comment: It looks like you have working code now. The Document Variable is static. It has one value that you can change, just as your method changes the text. It does not change automatically, like the Date field.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon: Ah, ok, I'll try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `.MoveEnd` after `.Collapse wdCollapseEnd` works:

```
VDate = "31.03.2022"    'String

Set WordRange = objDoc.Sections(1).Footers(WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

WordRange.Delete

With WordRange
    .Text = VDate & "  |  Page "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .Fields.Add WordRange, wdFieldPage
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .MoveEnd
    .InsertAfter " of "
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    .MoveEnd
    .Fields.Add WordRange, wdFieldNumPages
End With
```

[image]